# How to kill all the threads before deploying a liferay portlet

Tags: java, multithreading, liferay, liferay-6

I am using Liferay 6.2 with threads created using ServletContextListener.

So, when I try to deploy this specific portlet application, it gives me the following error -

```
INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl.  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1600)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.getProviderClass(FactoryFinder.java:112)
    at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:178)
    at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:147)
    at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:265)
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance(DocumentBuilderFactory.java:121)
    at com.h5g.deployment.util.DeploymentUtil.getLobbyBranch(DeploymentUtil.java:642)
    at com.h5g.deployment.service.ClientStatusCheckTask.call(ClientStatusCheckTask.java:47)
    at com.h5g.deployment.service.ClientStatusCheckTask.call(ClientStatusCheckTask.java:1)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

I'd been looking for a way to kill the threads before the auto deploy kicks in.

Any pointers would be really helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds a lot like you're creating the threads yourself - something that typically raises an eyebrow in an application server environment. There are several ways to mitigate this - the one with the least impact on your current (implied) architecture is that you need the threads to stop when you *undeploy* the web application. I'm assuming that this doesn't happen "on deploy", but rather "after undeploy" because you're starting your threads in the `ServletContextListener`, but are never stopping them.

A `ServletContextListener` gets notified when an application is shut down, this is what you can use to flag its state to the threads that you spawned. In the typical endless loop, the threads would frequently check if they still should be running - if they shouldn't, just exit the endless loop and they'll beautifully clean up behind them. When the application is redeployed, the new `ServletContextListener` will spawn new threads.

Answer (score 0):

try to stop threads with for:

```
thread.interrupt();
```

but i'm not sure i need to see code where you starts threads

Comment: Thanks for ur update. But, I believe, doing it programmatically would not be an ideal way. There has to be some way to handle this through the liferay configurations.